# Permalink with sub-sub-category and post name

Tags: permalinks, taxonomy

Working on a new theme project and I created a custom post type called products with its own custom taxonomy. 
I want the URL structure to be:

> ```
> http://example.com/products/main_category/subcategory1/subcategory2/postname/
> ```

I found this solution here:

```
function filter_post_type_link($link, $post)
    {
        if ($post->post_type == 'products')
            return $link;

        if ($cats = get_the_terms($post->ID, 'product_categories'))
            $link = str_replace('%product_categories%', array_pop($cats)->slug, $link);
        return $link;
    }
    add_filter('post_type_link', 'filter_post_type_link', 10, 2);
```

With this solution I was able to create this structure:

> ```
> http://example.com/products/category/postname/
> ```

So subcategories still won't show in the URL...

The other problem is that when I set the taxonomy `hierarchical => true` the url looks like this when I browse the product categories:

> ```
>  http://example.com/products/category1/subcategory1-category1/subcategory2-subcategory1-category1/
> ```

and also when `hierarchical => true` is present the code I mentioned above stops working.

So what I want to achieve with product urls basically is this:
If product belongs to the main category:

> ```
>  http://example.com/products/main_category/postname/
> ```

If product belongs to subcategory1:

> ```
>  http://example.com/products/main_category/subcategory1/postname/
> ```

If product belongs to subcategory2:

> ```
>  http://example.com/products/main_category/subcategory1/subcategory2/postname/
> ```

Of course if I delete post name from the above urls wp should show the appropriate category.
This would be a nice hierarchical structure.

Do You know any solutions to make this happen?

Best Wishes,
Matt

Answer (score 1):

Get rid of the filter that you have. Make sure that you use `'rewrite' => array( 'hierarchical' => 'true' )` in your `register_taxonomy()` function. Don't forget to flush the rewrite rules. See this page for more info: [Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy)